# Mapping only few properties instead of all using Automapper

Tags: automapper

I have recently started using automapper and it has work fine for me so far. I have been mapping domain objects to corresponding dtos and by default all source properties get mapped to their matching destination properties. I have been using code as follows:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Node, NodeDto>();
var nodeDto = Mapper.Map<Node, NodeDto>( node );
```

Now I have got into a situation where I would like to map only some of the properties of the source object. There are collection properties in the source object that I do not want to be mapped to the matching destination properties. Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could specify the properties to ignore like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Node, NodeDto>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.SomePropToIgnore, opt => opt.Ignore())
```

Comment: Hi Darin, Could you help me with an another issue I have just ran into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336688/issue-with-ignoring-nested-properties-using-automapper 
Thanks

Comment: and another issue on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336931/issue-with-ignoring-base-class-property-in-child-classes-mappings-using-automappe

Answer (score 1):

The marked answer is appropriate if you want to ignore a small set of properties. If you need to map a small set of properties using a TypeConverter might be more appropriate.

```
// Configure map using TypeConverter
cfg.CreateMap<MySource, MyDestination>()
                .ConvertUsing(new MyTypeConverter());


public class MyTypeConverter : ITypeConverter<MySource, MyDestination>
{
    
    public MyTypeConverter() : base()
    {
        
    }

    public MyDestination Convert(MySource source, MyDestination destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {            
         MyDestination myObj = destination == null ? new MyDestination() : destination;

         myObj.Prop1 = source.Prop1;
         myObj.Prop2 = source.Prop2;

         return myObj;            
    }
}
```

Comment: If I'm going to use a type converter why do I need to use automapper?

Comment: Perhaps, you are using automapper OOTB in several places in your application but you have a couple special cases that require custom type converters. Would you suggest abandoning automapper altogether in that scenario?